Converting a .NET Core generic class to a TypeScript Generic Class
I have model using generics for my .NET core backend which follows this structure:
public class ViewDataLayerModel<T>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("DATA")]
    public List<T> Data {get; set;} = new List<T>();

    [JsonPropertyName("CURRENT_PAGE")]
    public long Page {get; set;} = 1;

    [JsonPropertyName("TOTAL_PAGES")]
    public long TotalPages {get; set;}  

    [JsonPropertyName("MAX_RECORDS")]
    [Range(1, 500)]
    public int MaxRecords {get; set;}  = 500;
}

Now my data will always be sent to the frontend using this approach so on the frontend I am trying to get my interface together to conform to this same model (I find interfaces to be similar to models but I am new to typescript so forgive me if I am wrong). My interface translates to the following:
export interface DataLayer {
    Data: Array<object>;
    CURRENT_PAGE: number ;
    TOTAL_PAGES: number ;
    MAX_RECORDS: object | null;
}

However this triggers the error when I try to assign values as
Argument of type 'object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{review...

So I am thinking that Array<object> might not be the correct implementation of generics in TypeScript. How would my .NET model translate to this?

Well, what's T when you send it across? That's what Data should be an array of. So it would be interface DataLayer<T> { Data: T[]; ... But you'd have to specify T when you get the data.

T can be many different classes on the .Net api side. On the typescript side I have various other interfaces I have put together which match the .Net side which I was hoping can utilize the generic type for the DataLayer Interface.

You should not use Array of object. Typescript also has the concept of generics so you can create multiple Types or Interfaces to reflect the "T" type of your C# class.
There is a very cool .NET library called Reinforced.Typings that can help you auto generate typescript types from C# classes, definitely check it out.

To translate your .NET generic class ViewDataLayerModel<T> to TypeScript, use a generic interface.
Create a TypeScript interface DataLayer<T> with a generic type T.
export interface DataLayer<T> {
        Data: Array<T>;
        CURRENT_PAGE: number;
        TOTAL_PAGES: number;
        MAX_RECORDS: number;
    }

When using the DataLayer interface, specify the type of data it will contain (e.g., Review). This makes the interface flexible and reusable for different data types, ensuring type safety.
 interface Review {
        id: number;
        content: string;
    }
    
    const reviewDataLayer: DataLayer<Review> = {
        Data: [{ id: 1, content: "Great product!" }],
        CURRENT_PAGE: 1,
        TOTAL_PAGES: 5,
        MAX_RECORDS: 500
    };

